# "Mailbox size limit exceeded" when sending mails on an empty exchange account with MailKit .Net

Tags: vb.net, exchange-server, smtpclient, mailkit, mimekit

I am using MimeKit and Mailkit to send emails from my VB.NET application, through my own SMTP server (run on Windows Server 2016, with SmarterMail).

Until then, I was sending emails to info@mywebsite.com which is an alias of info**s**@mywebsite.com and it worked very well. This email account is a exchange account with more of 49 Gio free.

Since a few days, I've received this error : Mailbox size limit exceeded 
When a set a spy on it, this is what I get :

[image: Exception screenshot]

This is the log :

```
S: 235 Authentication successful
C: MAIL FROM:<info1@mywebsite.com> SIZE=599
S: 250 OK <info1@mywebsite.com> Sender ok
C: RCPT TO:<info@mywebsite.com>
S: 452 <info@mywebsite.com> Mailbox size limit exceeded
C: RSET
S: 250 OK
```

I don't understand why I get this error while my recipient account is pretty much empty.

- When I try to send email from my outlook account to info@mywebsite, I get no error.
- When I try to send emails from my code to anothers recipients, I get no error.
- My disk space is very large on my mail serveur (almost 2 To).

This is my code :

```
Dim message As New MimeMessage()
message.From.Add(New MailboxAddress("My website", "info1@mywebsite.com"))
message.To.Add(New MailboxAddress("My website", "info@mywebsite.com"))

message.Subject = "any subject"

Dim builder As New BodyBuilder()
builder.TextBody = textemail
builder.HtmlBody = htmlemail
message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody()

' SERVER SMTP
Using client As New MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient()
    client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (Function(sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) True)
    client.Connect("mail.mysmtpserver.com", 587, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.None)
    client.Authenticate("Mailkit_SMTP_UserName", "Mailkit_SMTP_Password")
    client.Send(message)
    client.Disconnect(True)
End Using
```

Thanks a lot for any suggestion (I don't find any related topic on Google)

Comment: Your best bet is to send an email to tech support for the server. This isn't really a programming question because there's no code changes that you can make to "fix" this issue.

Comment: I am the tech support for the serveur :) But you're right, It was indeed a server configuration issue, as I've found yesterday (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what was wrong in my SMTP server : Smartermail has it own mailbox size configuration for any mail account, that is limited at 100Mb.

You can change it by going on : your domain > Manage > Account